# Where does the increasing CPU load come from?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, profiler, cpu-usage

I do have problems with an application I developed. When I run it over long period of times, the CPU load goes slowly up. Here is a screenshot of Java VisualVM after 45 minutes.

[image]

As you can see, memory usage is very constant and the number of threads as well. The application opens a LAN socket and makes a measurement every 2 seconds. This measurement is running in a separate thread (which can be seen in the thread plot bottom right).

The CPU usage increases slowly but surely, overnight it accumulates to around 70-80% at which point the whole system is considerabely slowed down (obviously). Now I don't want this increase of course but can not find the reason for it. There is no memory leak (which would result in a continuous increase of memory as well) nor do I generate more and more threads (because that count is stable as well).

My app has an extensive GUI and several threads. Here is the thread list from the profiler:

[image]

I marked "my" threads yellow. So the `MeasurementCommunication.startMeasurement` threads are created (and terminated again) whenever needed. So there is only one of those guys running at any time.

**So to cut a long story short: I don't know where this CPU increase comes from. Do you have any ideas? Maybe that's a general Java problem?**
If you need any more information or details, just tell me and I try to answer them. ;)

Comment: Profile CPU usage and see where the hot-spots are when it's up.

Comment: Have you monitored GC time (with -verbose:gc for example)?

Comment: @assylias what would that bring? Do you think the GC does not do it's job correctly?

Comment: @bmargulies Ok, I will do that and get back with results. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Increasing GC time may show heap fragmentation issues or other problems.  What JVM version is this and on what OS?  Are you using any special VM parameters?  You are definitely _not_ running out of permgen, right?

Comment: @brimborium The GC probably does it job, but monitoring how long GCs take will tell you if this is an area that needs to be investigated further or not.

Comment: @Gray VM parameters are `-Xms128m -Xmx512m` and I think I am not running out of permgen. I will check that tomorrow morning after a night of profiling. And I will definitely look at the GC time as you and assylias suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding the close votes: If the guys can show me how to deal with this issue, thats not localized but very general and of good use for others having similar issues... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just having a look at your used heap, it does appear from 17:00 to go upwards, what you would need to do is to capture it for a longer period and ensure it does climb back down and keeps up/down but typically flat usage, if it starts to produce results like  steps i.e. incrementing further and further upwards then it could be a memory leak causing the issue which then impacts your cpu. so in short you need to watch it for longer specially when the heap climbs. So the state between each full garbage collection....

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will let it run over night. Maybe that gives me some more insight. How would a memory leak in Java work? Isn't the GC periodically freeing unused memory?

Comment: yep basically there are two forms of garbage collection : Full and partial - have a read on this on how to enable logging full gc or partial gc http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=63241  - then look through your logs for when it happened and check your graphs - the graphs on its own should give a clue - as mentioned if its a spiral like steps upwards then memory leak would be the cause..........